# how does cloudstack-oss differ from cloud.com?

Tags: linux, licensing, cloud-computing

the commercial offering (cloud.com) differs only by support?

cloudstack OSS is licensed under GPL v3, is that good for commercial usage (unmodified binaries)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently (as of August) there is no feature difference between the open source and commercial variants. (see http://news.slashdot.org/story/11/08/29/1653214/cloudstack-goes-open-source)

The open source variant is built for more distributions (Commercial is only built for RHEL5 and RHEL6, while OSS is built for Fedora and Ubuntu in addition to EL5 and EL6)

On the GPLv3 issue, you can modify CloudStack to your heart's content - you only need to distribute the source of your changes if you distribute your changes outside your organization.